# libGDX collision is delayed for some reason

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an object that rolls from one side of the screen to the other and when leaving the screen's border it moves to the starting point and repeat the process. Now every time the object reach the middle of the screen it collide with a rectangle and add a point to a counter.

Here is the collision code:

```
if (Intersector.overlaps(ball.getBoundingCircle(), myWorld.getRec())) GameWorld.addScore(1);
```

The problem is that at the first time the object collides with the rectangle, the point is been added, the second time it's not, the third time it is, the fourth time it's not and ever other time after it works fine.
Can someone tell me what may be the problem for the point to not be added in the second and fourth time?

EDIT: This is the full collision code for all four ball object as i mentioned in my comment bellow:

```
if (Intersector.overlaps(ball.getBoundingCircle(), myWorld.getRec())){ GameWorld.addScore(1);System.out.println("ball.");}
if (Intersector.overlaps(ball2.getBoundingCircle(), myWorld.getRec())){ GameWorld.addScore(1);System.out.println("ball2.");}
if (Intersector.overlaps(ball3.getBoundingCircle(), myWorld.getRec())){ GameWorld.addScore(1);System.out.println("ball3.");}
if (Intersector.overlaps(ball4.getBoundingCircle(), myWorld.getRec())){ GameWorld.addScore(1);System.out.println("ball4.");}
```

Comment: with that code you put in, the only thing I can think of is to try with a log if within 1 to see if it collides when you think and if so look at the code of addScore

Comment: OK, I needed to be more precise. I use for variables of a ball object that run on the screen and when each hit the rectangle it add a point, and when each leave the screen's border it moves to its start position. When I ran the code with the log, the second and the fourth objects didn't add a point on the first and second rounds of passing objects (balls), but from the third round they started to add a point and the log appeared right. The first and second rounds are the problems...

Comment: i think, you paste code GameWorld.addScore()

Comment: I just added the full collision code for all four balls. I checked again the code with the log and it appears that sometimes the balls add 1 after colliding and sometime they don't. It happen the most with the second and fourth balls, but if the game run for a long time it happen to the first and third ball as well...\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by increasing the width of the rectangle and radius of the circle.